# FROM keyword not where to be expected

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I'm getting the error **ora-00923** in Oracle in this query:

```
select trans_dt case trans_type="CR" then "Credit" else NULL end as "New" 
  from bank_transaction;
```

Answer (score 2):

Two (and two halves) objections:

- wrong syntax

  - missing comma between two columns
  - invalid `case` usage
- strings are to be enclosed into single, not double quotes
- however (that the first "half" part), column aliases can be enclosed into double quotes, as you did with the `"New"`
- finally (the second "half"), as Gordon commented, `else` is redundant (as it returns `null`) and can be omitted

So:

```
select trans_dt,
       case when trans_type = 'CR' then 'Credit' 
       end as "New" 
FROM bank_transaction;
```

For example:

```
SQL> select * From bank_transaction;

TRANS_DT   TR
---------- --
24.01.2020 CR
08.12.2019 XX

SQL> select trans_dt,
  2         case when trans_type = 'CR' then 'Credit'
  3         end as "New"
  4  FROM bank_transaction;

TRANS_DT   New
---------- ------
24.01.2020 Credit
08.12.2019

SQL>
```

Comment: . . I would also throw in that the `else null` is redundant and not needed.

Comment: ... and I would agree with you, @Gordon. Thank you.

Comment: Hi Littlefoot, need to mention about the interesting coincidence that our badge counts are exactly the same ( 9,18, 37 ) for each type :)

Comment: Ha! True, @Barbaros, nice catch :)

Answer (score 0):

Do it like this:
Look at the documentation for the use of case when and between field put a comma

```
select trans_dt, case when trans_type="CR" then "Credit" else NULL end as "New" 
FROM bank_transaction;
```